# yii2 валидация формы сценарий

Tags: yii2

Есть проблема с валидацией

....

```
  const SCENARIO_REGISTER_CLIENT_1 = 'REGISTER_C_1';
  const SCENARIO_REGISTER_MODEL_1 = 'REGISTER_M_1';
```

....

экшн
 public function actionSignup()
    {

```
    $this->layout = 'signup_layout';

    $model_client = new Signup();
    $model_model = new Signup();
    $model_client->scenario = Signup::SCENARIO_REGISTER_CLIENT_1;
    $model_model->scenario = Signup::SCENARIO_REGISTER_MODEL_1;
    if ($model_client->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->post())) {
        if ($user = $model_client->signup()) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }
    }
    if ($model_model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->post())) {
        if ($user = $model_model->signup()) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }
    }

    return $this->render('signup',[
        'model_client' => $model_client,
        'model_model' => $model_model,
    ]);
}
```

Теперь модель
в rules добавил

```
 //SCENARIOS MODEL
        ['contact_person','required','on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER_CLIENT_1],
        ['contact_person','string','min' => 2 , 'max'=> 255,'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER_CLIENT_1],
```

это поле которого нет в обычном сценарии

теперь когда отправляю model_model сценарий
метода `$this->validation` выдает ошибку
что сценарий не найден

```
Unknown scenario: REGISTER_M_1
```

не пойму где нужно поправить?

логика такая , есть общие поля - они обрабатываются в любом случае
есть сценарии с спецефичными полями, если нет спец полей для сценария - должен обработать общие
так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

добавил к каждому 'общему полю'  массив со сценариями

```
'on' => [self::SCENARIO_REGISTER_CLIENT_1, self::SCENARIO_REGISTER_MODEL_1]
```

но данное решение мне не особо нравится.
кто знает более изящное решение?